# Pretty-print haskell source code with comments

Tags: haskell, pretty-print

I'm trying to reformat/reprint haskell source code (remove/add whitespace, linebreaks, change indention style...). I've found the package [haskell-src-exts](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/haskell-src-exts-1.11.1) which can parse and pretty-print haskell source code.

Using the function `parseFileWithComments :: ParseMode -> FilePath -> IO (ParseResult (Module, [Comment]))` I also get the comments included in the source code. Now I want to print the Module/AST with the comments at the original positions, but I cannot find a function which will do that. I can only pretty-print the AST. Do I have to implement printing of the AST plus the comments myself or does such a library already exist?

To clarify consider following example:

file A.hs:

```
module A (fn1) where

-- | Haddock-comment
fn1 ::
    String ->
    String
fn1 _ = "" -- another comment
```

In ghci, typing

```
Prelude Control.Monad.Reader Language.Haskell.Exts> (liftM prettyPrint) $ (liftM fst) $ (liftM fromParseResult) $ parseFileWithComments defaultParseMode "A.hs"`
```

prints the module source code (without the comments, of course). I can use any `prettyPrint`-function to modify the source code formatting.

Now I want to be able to do something like this:

```
do
    (ast, comments) <- fromParseResult $ parseFileWithComments defaultParseMode "A.hs"
    prettyPrintWithComments ast comments
```

to get a pretty-printed version of the original file including the comments.

Answer (score 6):

Use the `Annotated` versions of the modules, e.g. `Language.Haskell.Exts.Annotated` vs `Language.Haskell.Exts`.

Comment: That's quite helpful, but not exactly what I wanted. I still want to be able to reformat the actual source code with a configured pretty-print `Style` and `PPHsMode`.

Comment: @haja: why can't you?  It's still an instance of haskell-src-ext's `Pretty` class...

Comment: but then again, how can the original comments be included in the pretty-print output? I can't find a function which pretty-prints the ast _including_ comments.

Comment: @haja: OK, my mistake: I thought that comments were included in the AST.  However, does the `Language.Haskell.Exts.Annotated.ExactPrint` module solve your issue?

Comment: sadly not, since I still want to reformat the source code, which is not possible with `Language.Haskell.Exts.Annotated.ExactPrint`. It only prints the source code exactly as it was before parsing.

Comment: @haja From that module: *"The input is a (semi-concrete) abstract syntax tree, annotated with exact source information"* - doesn't that mean you can modify that *format* syntax tree and `ExactPrint` will then print it according to your formatting changes?

Comment: @nh2 I'm afraid I don't really understand what you mean. There is no _format_ syntax tree, just an _abstract syntax tree_. The format is applied to the printed output, not to the ast. The ast stays the same.

Comment: @haja I was suggesting the following: You call e.g. `exactPrint m comments` where `m` might be `Module SrcLoc`. You could transform `m` so that it looks like what you want, modifying the `SrcLoc`s; same with the `comments`. Yes, that is probably tedious and complicated. I emailed the maintainer of haskell-src-exts (see hackage page), and apparently he is interested in making tasks like this more convenient. I suggested an intermediate parse tree with all information (comments and whitespace) present. Perhaps you should join the discussion.

Answer (score 3):

Depending on what kind of pretty printing do you want to do, you might want to take a look at the [`hscolour`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/hscolour) package, which is used to colorize Haskell source code into various output formats.

In particular, the module [Language.Haskell.HsColour.Classify](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/hscolour/1.19/doc/html/Language-Haskell-HsColour-Classify.html) contains a Haskell tokenizer which preserves whitespace and comments, which might serve as a good starting point.

Comment: thanks, but I'm not looking for this kind of pretty-printing. I updated my question to clarify what kind of pretty-printing I want.